# How can I initialize 15-20 sprites with the same starting position?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios, cocos2d

How can I load 15-20 sprites in Cocos2D at the same point (`ccp(20,20)`, which is an alias for `CGPointMake`) using `NSArray`?
This is what I'm doing now, and it doesn't work:

```
int i,endvalue=3;
NSMutableArray *levelStar = [ [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9 ];
for(i=1;i<=endvalue;i++)
{
    CCSprite *star = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image"+i+".png"];
    star.position = ccp( 20,20);
    [levelStar addObject:star];
    [self addChild:star];
}
```

Comment: Please edit your [previous question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19514/how-to-load-a-sprite-individually-and-stable-its-position-in-the-board) instead of asking a new one.  Thank you.

Comment: -1. Put some effort into that question, so that it's actually answerable. You don't tell us what doesn't work. We don't know if these files you try to load are actually there and in the title you write about *20 sprites* and then in your question it's suddenly *15 sprites*?

Comment: leave the count place the 15 or 20 sprite image in the same ccp point just need that then i will ask the further things later

Comment: if you dont no to answer dont downvote it, it doesnt make sense,if you know answer post it otherwise dont discourage it

Comment: I do not downvote questions when I don't know the answer. I downvote when I think the question is unanswerable in its current form, simply because it's not clear at all what you want to do.

Comment: by asking previous question explained a lot,you not able to answer,you downvote yourself by not knowing the answer for the previous question

Comment: I agree with bummzack, both of your questions on this subject are very underspecified: it isn't clear what you want, and what is going wrong. I would suggest you check out [this excellent article](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) on asking good questions as well as this more recent piece on [explaining the research effort you've already put forth](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 2):

While it is extremely unclear what you are doing and what you are considering behavior that "doesn't work," I want to point out that there is a huge discrepancy with your question (which asked about setting up 15 to 20 sprites) and your code, which may be the root of your troubles. Specifically, you have this loop:

```
int i, endvalue=3;
for(i = 1; i <= endvalue; i++) {
  ....
}
```

This loop only executes three times. So you're only setting up and adding three sprites to the array total. Perhaps you meant to write your loop this way?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
  ...
}
```